# Using capacitive touch screen without human hand

Tags: batteries, wire, charge, capacitive, touchscreen

I'm trying to learn more about how to engage a capacitive touchscreen without using a human finger. Full disclaimer I'm in mechanical engineering (notoriously known to have difficulty comprehending concepts not physically observable), so I'll try and understand as best I can to your responses. I've done some of my own research and came across this thread which asked a similar question:
[How to use a capacitive touch screen without a human hand](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60385/how-to-use-a-capacitive-touch-screen-without-a-human-hand/60424#60424?)

My question is, however, is it possible to stimulate the touchscreen with a electrically conductive plate that is connected to a battery via a wire? If I understand correctly from the attached link, I would need a way to connect the touchscreen to a much larger body such as our own bodies, but would this be just as, if not more effective when connected to the negative terminal of a battery (theoretically speaking)?

And just to clarify, there would be no need to provide any current from the battery to make this work correct?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You shouldn't need a battery. After all, does your body need a battery? A capacitor should work, and your body does not have that much capacitance compared to an electronic component built as a cap. Easy enough to test.

Comment: _"how to engage a capacitive touchscreen without using a human finger"_ - why would you want to do this?

Comment: You just need to have a conductive tip attached to the same ground as the touch screen circuit. Google "capacitive touch screen production test". There are pneumatic activated tips available if you don't want to make your own with a touch screen pen or similar.